# log(1+x) is to log1p as log(1-x) is to?

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

`<math.h>` provides a more accurate method for computing `log(1+x)` for `double`s.

Is there a similarly precise manner for computing `log(1-x)`?

The reason I ask is because I'm trying to do some work in log-space for greater precision (I'm mostly multiplying and summing numbers very close to zero). I found it easy to write a function that gives `log( exp(log_of_a) + exp(log_of_b) ) = log( a + b )` by using `log1p`. I am trying to make a similar function for the difference:

`log( exp(log_of_a) - exp(log_of_b) ) = log( a - b )`
*where `a > b`, of course.*

Essentially, as long as neither `log_a` or `log_b` `== -inf`, the function should simply return:

```
return log( 1 - exp(log_b-log_a) ) + log_a;
```

In my `log_add` function, I end up with a `log( 1 + ... )`, and so I use `log1p`. But here I have `log( 1 - ... )`. Just in case, I even googled log1m, but no luck...

When the argument `x` is in the range `[-inf, 1)`, then I could simply use `log1p(-x)` (given my assertion `a > b`).

Is that the **best** way to go about solving this? I feel I must be doing work that has been done before...

I'd really appreciate your help knowing how to get the most accurate results I can (or explaining why I can't get results more accurate than this).

Comment: I assume you mean `log( exp(log_of_a) - exp(log_of_b) ) = log( a - b )`, right? You have `a + b`.

Comment: +1 Oops! Good catch. It's late...

Comment: Negation of floating point numbers is exact, so `log1p(-x)` is as accurate as `log1p(x)`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

@Raymond Chen is spot on: "Negation of floating point numbers is exact, so `log1p(-x)` is as accurate as `log1p(x)`." Just making it into a real answer.

Comment: log1p(-x) is indeed a fine way to do it, but I think this answer is misleading in that it sounds like it's making a precise statement but it's really not.  If you think it is, please say exactly what you mean by "is as accurate", and then clarify the leap from "negation of floating point numbers is exact" to "log1p(-x) is as accurate as log1p(x)".